# Cancel button doesn't work in function alert_remove()

Tags: php, function, alert

i want to display a **Yes No message** when deleting records,
i tried this code, it works fine but the **No button** also work as **Yes button** which means even if i click **No** it delete that record

```
<script language="javascript">
   function alert_remove() {
      confirm("Are u sure u want to delete ?");
   }
</script>
```

```
<a rel='tooltip' title='Delete' href='actions.php?delete=$row->id' onClick='javascript:alert_remove();'>
```

actions.php file :

```
        if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
            $id = $_GET['delete'];
            $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$id");
            header("Location: liste.php");
        }
```

Comment: Please share more details - what's your question about this? What **exactly** is not working as expected? Also, please be warned that your query is widely open for SQL injection - better have a look at prepared statements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You need to return false

To prevent navigation, the `onclick` function has to return `false`.

> ```
> onClick='javascript:alert_remove();'
> ```

It has no `return` statement, so it returns nothing.

So:

1. Remove the pointless [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)
2. Add a `return` statement

Such:

```
onclick='return alert_remove();'
```

---

Now you are returning the return value of `alert_remove`, but that function doesn't have a return statement either, so you need to add one:

```
   function alert_remove() {
      return confirm("Are u sure u want to delete ?");
   }
```

---

## Asides

### Out of date HTML

> ```
> <script language="javascript">
> ```

This is HTML 3.2. The current version of HTML is HTML 5. Write to the current standards:

```
<script>
```

… and [use a validator](https://validator.nu/).

### Invalid HTML

> ```
> rel='tooltip'
> ```

This is not a registered value for `rel`.

If you want to add arbitary data to an element for access with JavaScript, use a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

### GET should not be used to delete things

> ```
> href='actions.php?delete=$row->id'
> ```

Deleting things is not a safe operation. The HTTP specification reserves GET requests for safe operations.

There was an incident where a browser plugin, designed to speed up browsing by prefetching subsequent pages, deleted lots of posts on a forum because an admin user had it installed and the form used links to delete posts.

If you want to delete things, use a `<form>` and make a POST request.

### Out of date and insequre database access

> ```
> mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$id");
> ```

You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) that has been [removed](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) from PHP. This means that you are using a version of PHP which hasn't had a security fix since 2018. Upgrade PHP as soon as possible.

You should select a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for your database API.

What's more, you are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

### Intrinsic event attributes have issues

They have a number of gotchas and haven't been considered best practise since the 90s. We have [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) now.